# dplyr distinct column values sql

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I use dplyr in conjunction with a PostgreSQL data base which makes a reproducible example a bit hard for me. Anyways, I want to use the `distinct` function to filter out messy data, i.e. duplicate `timestamp`s. So far I have:

```
db <- src_postgres(dbname = "a", host = "b", port = 1234,
                   user = "c")

measurements <- tbl(adres_db, "measurement")

sites <- group_by(measurements, site)

sites_clean <- filter(sites,
                      site < 38)

sites_clean <- distinct(sites_clean, timestamp)

P_stats <- summarise(
  sites_clean,
  count = n(),
  P = mean(p_sum)
)

collect(P_stats)
```

I get the error:

`Error: Can't calculate distinct only on specified columns with SQL`

Is there a workaround for this? Will dplyr support this in a future version?

**Update**

I followed the documentation and created a minimal working example using a sqlite data base (also thanks beginneR for the %>% reminder)

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)

meas <- data.frame(id = 1:30,
                   timestamp = sample(Sys.time() + c(1,2,3) * 3600,
                     size = 30, replace = TRUE),
                   site = sample(c(1, 2, 40), size = 30, replace = TRUE),
                   p_sum = rpois(30, 2))

meas_sqlite <- copy_to(my_db, meas, temporary = FALSE)

meas_tbl <- tbl(my_db, "meas")

P_stats <- group_by(meas_tbl, site, timestamp) %>%
  summarise(P = mean(p_sum)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  filter(site < 38) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), P = mean(P))

collect(P_stats)
```

While this works, I feel it is not as clean as it could be. Also I need to try the suggestion with `row_number(timestamp) == 1` on the PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: Group by timestamp then select the first row of each group?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried with `times <- group_by(sites_clean, timestamp)` and then `times_dedup <- slice(times, 1)` and it says `no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_postgres', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl')"`

Comment: After reading the fine documentation I found that I should use `filter(sites_clean, row_number() == 1)` instead of `slice`, but I get an `RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "measurement.site" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3: FROM (SELECT "site", "timestamp", count(*) AS "count", AVG("...`

Comment: You'll need `row_number(something)` because DB's have no notion of order

Comment: Just a side note: you could use dplyr's `%>%` operator so you don't need to create many different versions/subsets of your data.